# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'users' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am using Gmail API to Send Email. but getting an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'users' of undefined

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function sendMessage(email, callback) {
        // Web-safe base64 
        var base64EncodedEmail = btoa(email).replace(/\//g, '_').replace(/\+/g, '-');
        var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.send({
            'userId': 'me',
            'message': {
                'raw': base64EncodedEmail
            }
        });
        request.execute(callback);
    }

    function send() {


        var to = 'vijay@itsabacus.com',
         subject = 'Hello World',

         content = 'send a Gmail.'
        var email = "From: 'me'\r\n" +
            "To:  " + to + "\r\n" +
            "Subject: " + subject + "\r\n" +
            "\r\n" +
            content;
            sendMessage(email, function () {
            console.log(arguments);
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `gapi.client.gmail` must be null or undefined thus the error

Comment: how can i solve this issue. Please Explain.

Comment: Try putting debug point in browser debugger and check why you are getting this error.

Comment: Please give me link , from where i can download, Gmail API Client Library,

Comment: I am using Code from - https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send#examples     , i am running this code and getting this error    Uncaught ReferenceError: gapi is not defined

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same issue and for me I needed to do something like the following:

```
gapi.load('client:auth2', () => {
    gapi.client.load('gmail', 'v1', () => {
      console.log('Loaded Gmail');
    });
}
```

After that in the debugger I could use the gmail api as you have above:

```
gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.send({...});
```

Hope this helps.